# Does Hakuoro come back at the end?

Tags: utawarerumono

In the ending of the visual novel, Kamyu looked away from Aruru and said "Oji-sama" (which is how she referred to Hakuoro), then Aruru told Kamyu to jump on Mukkuru and rode off. The scene after that shows Eruru in what is believed to be her home village rebuilt. Though it could be just the developers reusing the background, it shows an isometric view of the village, which looks almost as if the village had been repaired. The final CG shows her looking towards the screen almost in shock.

I haven't seen the anime so I have no idea if this is elaborated on further. However, it almost seems as if Kamyu and Aruru saw Hakuoro and he returned to Eruru. Hakuoro also said before he was sealed that he would one day see Eruru again. However, he could have been referring to how Eruru was a decedent of his ancient daughter.

So I am wondering if Hakuoro did come back.